# select next node html Agility pack C#

Tags: c#, regex, filtering, html-agility-pack

I'm a student working with htmlagilitypack for the 1st time. I'm currently filtering the html to get the values using

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in bodyNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='content-b']"))
{
    if (link.InnerText.Contains("Name"))
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Found");
        textBox1.Text += "Name : " + ?????;
    }

    textBox1.Text += link.InnerText;
}
```

As you can see, I'm checking if the current node contains a value "NAME" and if so i want to get the next node's value next to it. I will be very thankful if you can help me out with this.

The Value of the name is in the next node `<div class='content-b'>THIS IS MY NAME</div>` .. how can i problematically tell C# to get the next node before looping again ?

Thank you.

---

Update : Here is the html code fragment that im working with, It Looks ugly , I'm sorry I can't help it

```
<span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Name of the Author: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Undertaker</font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Name movie: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Some Movie Name</font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Room Online: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">skype123</font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Subsites and site: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">google.nl</font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Year: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">2013. </font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Genre: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Horror</font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Length: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">00:35:45 </font></font></span></span></span></span><span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class="">Description: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font class=""><font>Paragraph 1</font><font>Paragraph 2</font><font>Paragraph 3</font></font><br></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font>Video Format: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font>MP4 </font></font></span></span></span></span> <span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font>Video: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font>MPEG4 Video (H264) 720x404 29.97fps 1000Kbps </font></font></span></span></span></span><span class="post-align" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Kristen ITC;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: normal;"><span style="color: #009933;"><span class="content-b"><font><font>Audio: </font></font></span></span> <span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;"><span class="content-b"><font><font>AAC 44100Hz stereo 96Kbps</font></font></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add a sample framgment of your HTML that contains your both required nodes.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn : I Added The HTML Fragment

Comment: Wow! Very hard to read HTML! I'l try to simplify it.

Comment: It is not a well-formed HTML. Were did you get that from? It contains a whole lot of unclosed tags, redundant closed tags and invalid nestings. Non of the `<div>` tags are closed. It is obvious that `HTML Agility Pack` can't figure it out.

Comment: Its from a community forum. i have no control over the source.
i'm getting values correctly from the loop though , the only problem is to get the value of the next **link** in **bodynode**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is no `class="content-b"` in your document. They are all spelled as **`contet-b`**.

Secondly, since the html is not well-formed, `NextSibling` will not work. You need to manually get the next node matching the criteria. You can't use a `foreach` loop in this situation.

Here is the result:

```
var nodes = bodyNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='contet-b']").ToList();
for( int i =0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    var link = nodes[i];
    if (link.InnerText.Contains("Name"))
    {
        textBox1.Text += "Name : ";
        if (i + 1 < nodes.Count)
        {
            // append the value of next matching `div` node
            textBox1.Text += nodes[i + 1].InnerText.Trim();
            i++; // skip this node
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **NextSibling** property of node. In your example:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in bodyNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content-b']"))
{
    if (link.InnerText.Contains("Name"))
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Found");
        textBox1.Text += "Name : " + link.NextSibling.InnerText;
    }

    textBox1.Text += link.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ultra fast response but it produces an error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I tried this solution before too but it never worked

Comment: Can you share fragment of your html with both of required nodes?

Comment: i updated the post with html fragments that i'm currently working with.